# Updating symfony 2.0.0-DEV to newer version

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.0

I have a symfony-project (2.0.0-DEV = RC5) which i want to upgrade to the latest version (2.0.18). 
If i just copy my bundles with some changes (for example autoloading path) it still don't work and throwing many errors. Of course i can fix all errors, but there a lot of bundles and it will take too much time. I have think about searching all posts from July 2011 and applying all changes from each release, but i think it too will take much time.

Is there any easier way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in [the update file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.0.18/UPDATE.md) there shouldn't be any significant change between RC5 and 2.0.18.

You should read [the CHANGELOG-2.0 file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.0.18/CHANGELOG-2.0.md) and update your code. It will take a lot of time.

You can do some other things aswell:

- You can wait till February 2013. Symfony2.2 comes out and you can change your code to work on Symfony2.2. In November 2013 you can upgrade to Symfony2.3, which is a [Long Term support release](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#long-term-support-releases). This means you will get support for 3 years after the release and not the normal 8 months.
- You can wait till November 2013, this is a really long time, and upgrade straight to Symfony2.3. You have to make one migration here, so it could be easier than the previous options.

The problem is that there isn't something like 'an easy way'. That's why Symfony gets into a Release Process Circle and LTR. You need to choose a way that is good for your application and will not take much time. That's why I don't recommend to upgrade to the latest 2.0.x or 2.1.x version, because that is only supported 8 months. The best is to use the 2.3 in November 2013 and update your application on a regular base (which is easy with composer). But November 2013 is almost a year, which I think is to long.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation! I'll wait until version 2.2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use composer for that. I could explain it to you, but I think that experts from KnpLabs company will do that better: http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/composer :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Composer is used in Symfony2.1 not 2.0. And you get the same errors if you install the update with composer. If you have 2.0.0RC5 and you upgrade it to 2.1.3 you get a lot more errors

Comment: You are wrong, you can use composer for almost any symfony version you want. Check it out https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony

So if you want to have symfony 2.0.18 you write in your composer.json

    "symfony/symfony" : "2.0.18"